# Dynamic Link based on User Roles

Tags: dynamic

What I'm trying to do is to have a dynamic link where the link would depend on the role of the user who is logged in.

I need this so that when a user is logged in and clicks on a button or link at the header - which also appears when logged in - it will take the user to a certain link where he/she is allowed to view.

I'm trying to do this in wordpress and using elementor - not sure if that helps.

```
<code><pre>
function custom_dynamic_link() {
    // Check if the user is logged in
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        // Get the current user's roles
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $user_roles = $user->roles;

        // Check if the user has a specific role (e.g., "subscriber")
        if (in_array('Administrator', $user_roles)) {
             // Generate a link for subscribers
            $link = '/products'; // Replace with your desired link
        } elseif (in_array('allen_users', $user_roles)) {
            // Generate a link for editors
            $link = 'https://ohiofsbo.info/allen-user-role-test/'; // Replace with your desired link
        }elseif (in_array('ashland_users', $user_roles)) {
            // Generate a link for editors
            $link = 'https://ohiofsbo.info/ashland-user-role-test/'; // Replace with your desired link
        } else {
            // Default link for other roles
            $link = 'https://ohiofsbo.info/'; // Replace with your desired link
        }
    } else {
        // Default link for non-logged-in users
        $link = '/'; // Replace with your desired link
    }

    return $link;
}
```